# Update textview from onPostExecute in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have a textview that i would like to update each time my asynctask is complete.

But from what ive read so far it can only be done in `onPostExecute` if you use `setContentView()` before. But since i dont know which view the user is currently in when the task completes, it doesnt sound like a good solution to me. And even if i can get the current view, woudlnt `setContentView()` redraw the view?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you "know which view the user is currently in"?

Comment: @Squonk Because depending on what activity the user is currently viewing, he might be looking at something else than the "home" view

Comment: OK, so please use the word Activity instead of View (which is a completely different class). Also, to answer the question - define an `Interface` and have all of your `Activities` implement it in their own way. Then all you need to do is call the relevant method on the `Interface` from `onPostExecute`.

Comment: If he is in Activity B, then you app should not care and update TextView in Activity A, which is considered as a really bad practice. You should redraw Activity A with latest data once user back from Activity B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that `AsyncTask` is a good fit when the current user interface needs to be updated by the task. In your case, I would probably try and see whether a `Service` may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

As I know and always use AsyncTask performs heavy duty without blocking main UI thread. Means user operates some activity when time consuming job needs to be done. AsyncTask does that job and reflects result on UI. User happy. If you don't know where user is, then probably AsyncTask is not a right solution and you need a Service. It will do job and send a notification that something is ready. Tappi9ng notification will open activity with some data.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the UI thread from a worker thread, you must use a Handler or the method runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable).

Comment: Ok, are both asynctasks and services considered as worked threads?

Comment: An AsyncTask is a separate thread from what shows the UI, so it is considered a worker thread. I have not used Services personally, so I can't speak as to how they are handled.